# How to select a video from the gallery and get it's real path?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I can open the gallery with this code,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("video/*");

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST );
```

It works well on a Samsung Galaxy S5. But in some phones, images are displayed along with videos.

What changes do I need to do to the code to open the gallery to display **only** videos?

How can I get the real path of the selected video when the results are returned?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

---

Here is the full code to get the video path after selecting from gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                // OI FILE Manager
                filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedImagePath != null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                            VideoplayAvtivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", selectedImagePath);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // UPDATED!
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: the get path is returning null does it work for video ?

Comment: managedQuery is user defined function  ? please post that also

Comment: @JPn it is not user defined function.
method was deprecated in API level 11, use CursorLoader instead.
see this link [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery)

Comment: get path returning null

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari how did you make it work for video?

Comment: @Abubakar use `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA ` in getPath()

Comment: This example produces an intent output like dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:487 and they cannot be used as an uri in android 7

Comment: @Rohit Heera I am getting path as null ,using above code

Comment: @SagarHudge on Which version of android you try to get the path

Comment: @RohitHeera 6.0.1 and 7.0 i have tried on this version

Comment: @SagarHudge The way to read the data and also get picture using camera is changed in 7.0 Please check file provider system using XML. There you get your answer.

Comment: There has to be a cleaner way to do this? Has anyone discovered a library or framework that can efficiently help with this common task?

Comment: cursor should be freed up after use with #close()

Comment: It's return null always.

Comment: If your android version is 7.0 and above you need to setup fileprovider xml.

Comment: in samsung phone getting null

Comment: Now in API lever 7.0 onwards implent fileprovider for getting imgaes from camera and gallery

Comment: path gives null, improve the answer

Comment: Yes, the path gives null. The answer is not working

Answer (score 15):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent , SELECT_VIDEO);
```

Comment: This let's you select only one video.

Answer (score 11):

**You will get real Path from this method getPath**

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static MultipartBody.Part getMultiPartBody(String key, String mMediaUrl) {
    if (mMediaUrl != null) {
        File file = new File(mMediaUrl);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(key, file.getName(), requestFile);
    } else {
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(key, "");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This script is the only one that really work to get gallery img path. Thanks

Comment: Only thing that worked for me. It's amazing that there isn't something easier in this day and age

Comment: thanks, this is the only real working solution, may be from https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse project source

Comment: @M.J.Ahmadi it's not from any project, in my production project I solve the issue by using this code.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin Version

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
 intent.type = "video/*";
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CODE)
```

Then,

```
fun parsePath(uri: Uri?): String? {
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, null, null, null)
        return if (cursor != null) {
            val columnIndex: Int = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        } else null
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_VIDEO_CODE -> {
                val videoUri: Uri = data?.data!!
                val videoPath = getPath(videoUri)
                Log.d("TAG", "$videoPath is the path that you need...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i haven't specified `type()`, it was opening image picker, i don't know why??

Answer (score 2):

Below code works for me:

```
Intent videoPickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
videoPickIntent.setType("video/*");
TheActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(videoPickIntent, "Please pick a video"), PickIntroductionVideo);
```

and in onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode != PickIntroductionVideo)
    return;
if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
    return true;
String pickedVideoUrl = FarayanUtility.getRealPathFromUri(getContext(), data.getData());
```

Method `FarayanUtility.getRealPathFromUri` is:

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin Update - December, 2022

Most answers above are okay but I wanted to add an updated version of the answer for developers in 2022 or later working with Kotlin. The code works on a fragment instead of an activity since one-activity apps are the modern Google-recommended pattern.

### Launching the Video intent

First, we start by launching the intent. As of writing this answer, `startActivityForResult` has been deprecated, and instead an `activityResultLauncher` is used. Using `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` on the intent throws some warnings so I will avoid using it here. Here is the new version of the code compared to the old one;

##### Old way

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
intent.type = "video/*";
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CODE)
```

##### New Way

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null)
intent.type = "video/*"
resultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

And then create a result launcher

```
private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        
        // For null safety, make sure data is not null
        if (data == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Data returned is null")
            return@registerForActivityResult
        }
        
        val videoUri: Uri = data?.data!!
        val videoPath = parsePath(videoUri)

        // Do something with either the path or video Uri as needed
    }
}
```

### Getting file path

Once you get the video Uri, you can perform whatever action you want with it but for the benefit of the question, we will get the path. The `parsePath()` method is as shown below.

```
private fun parsePath(uri: Uri?): String? {
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
    val cursor: Cursor? = requireActivity()
        .contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, null, null, null)
    return if (cursor != null) {
        val columnIndex: Int = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val path = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        cursor.close() // Make sure you close cursor after use

        path
    } else null
}
```

Comment: hi I am getting error for the requireActivity(). Can you suggest what's wrong?

Comment: You're most likely not inside a fragment. `requireActivity()` and `getActivity()` can only be called from inside a fragment. If you are inside an activity, use `this` keyword instead. If outside both a fragment and an activity, you might have to pass around your activity (which is not very recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tested Kotlin Code. Works fine!

```
    private fun openGalleryForVideo() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "video/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),Constants.REQUEST_VIDEO)
    }
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_VIDEO){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if (data?.data != null) {
                    val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
                    val videoFullPath = uriPathHelper.getPath(requireContext(), data.data!!)
                    if (videoFullPath != null) {
                        val file = File(videoFullPath)
                        UploadVideoAPICall(file)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class URIPathHelper {

    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKatorAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatorAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                }

            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();

            // OI FILE Manager
            String filemanagerstring = selectedVideoUri.toString();
            vidPath = filemanagerstring;

            // MEDIA GALLERY
            String selectedVideoPath = getPath(selectedVideoUri); 
            if (selectedVideoPath != null) {
                vidPath = selectedVideoPath;
            }
        }
    }
}

//this function returns null when using IO file manager
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index); 
    } else
        return null;
}
```

If the `getpath()` function is returning "null" then its probably because you haven't set the permissions correctly. What you need to do is to paste this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Paste this before the `<application>` tag, then, once you load your app, go to settings-> applications-> YourApp -> permissions and then set all the permissions to true. Once you do that, this code should work perfectly

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent,
                            CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
imagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

}

  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: method inside method is not possible