# How do I specify local location with VideoView in Android?

Tags: android

I have a video in the device where I am running an Android app. How do I know its path so I can play it via my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the user select the video from the gallery to get its path and then start playing it.

- [select video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044591/how-to-select-a-video-from-the-gallery-and-get-its-real-path?answertab=active#tab-top)
- [start playing the selected video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040226/how-to-play-a-video-file-in-android)