# How to pick only videos from gallery?

Tags: android, video, android-gallery

I want to be able to pick only videos from gallery but I only found tutorials that   select images but I only  want to be able to select videos.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a video from the gallery and get it's real path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044591/how-to-select-a-video-from-the-gallery-and-get-its-real-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, when you use an intent, you can set the type of your intent. Here I'm using `"video/*"` to get all videos of my device.

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
startActivity(galleryIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
  protected int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO = 3;

            Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
```